# How to transition between view controllers

Tags: iphone

I have placed code in my App Delegate such that I can transition from one view controller to another.

However when I press the button, the transition to my `SecondViewController` is not made. How should I go about doing this? any simple way to bring next view controller,(pushview controller)...

Here is my code:

```
SecondViewController *aSecondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self setSecondViewController:aSecondView];
[aSecondView release];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                       forView:window
                         cache:YES];
[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window addSubview:[secondViewController view]];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: You're at 8 questions and 0 answers. Not good. You should go back and mark some of them answered.

Answer (score 1):

While you haven't posted more of your code so I can't be certain, there's a code smell coming from doing your controller transitions inside your app delegate. Since you describe a button that initiates the transition, my question is, why aren't you using a navigation controller and/or presenting your second view controller modally, inside the view controller that owns the button?

Modify your app delegate judiciously -- I mostly only use mine for doing one-time, global tasks, such as loading a Core Data store/sqlite database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're not using the built-in functions for presenting view controllers, you will have to call all of the `view*Appear:` functions:

- -viewWillAppear:
- -viewDidAppear:
- -viewWillDisappear:
- -viewDidDisappear:

I'm not sure if that will fix the problem, though.  You may want to instead use `presentModalViewController:animated:` to push the new view.  If it's not logically a subview of the current view, then have a root view push the first view, then when you want to transition, dismiss the first view and present the second from the (never seen) root view.